# last index array without loop

Tags: javascript, object, position

Good morning/afternoon

I Want to create an object whitch simulate an array, for new browsers no pb I change the **proto** of an array with mine but for oldest version of  IE i need to know the length of my false array by finding the last index.
I have found a way for IE:

```
var getLastPos = function(){
    for( var i in falseArray){
       //do nothing
    }
    return i 
}
```

but if a faster way exists, it rather like. I try to pass regex to lastindexof 
but it seems don't work
thanks.

Answer (score 0):

when you want to find the last index from the array, use

```
<array>.length
```

So you do not need the for loop, and your function, use

```
falseArray.length
```

If you need the value from the last position use something like this:

```
falseArray[falseArray.length-1] 
//decrement by one, because the index from the array starts by 0
```

I hope this is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Thks for you reply,
It was a old question, but I will answer, my goal was to create a false array in order to not polluate prototype.
By false array I mean an object who have the same behavior than a array with .length property and the use of '[]'.

My conclusion is that it is only possible at the class level with new Browser that allow to modify the proto

Ex:

```
 var myClassArray = function(){
        var obj = []
        obj.__proto__ = myClassArr.prototype
        return obj
    }
    myClassArr.prototype = Array;//inheritance
    myClassArr.prototype.last = function(){
        return this[this.length-1]
    }
```

or for old browser at object level

```
var myClassArray = function(){
    var obj = []
    obj.last=  function(){
       return this[this.length-1]
    }
    return obj
}
```

how to use it:

```
var myArray = new myClassArray;
console.log(myArray.length) //0
myArray[5]=1;
console.log(myArray.length) //6
console.log(myArray.last()) //1
```

Conclusion:
Modifiying the proto is a bad idea about perf and old browser.
 you can improve the code for old browser by creating function outside the class constructor else browser will duplicate function.

```
 var last = function(){
     return this[this.length-1]
 }
  var myClassArray = function(){
        var obj = []
        obj.last = last
        return obj
    }

var a = new myClassArray
var b = myClassArray()//In fact new is facultative
b.last == a.last //same ref no duplication
```